# Creating Sql statements based on input from querystring

Tags: php

I dynamically create sql statements for execution based on the url. I do them like this:

```
URL (using htaccess):
`http://www.example.com/us/california/sanjose`

Which translates to:
`http://www.example.com/index.php?country=US&state=california&sub=sanjose`

Then, in my script I do:
$sql = 'select * from table where';

if(isset($_GET['country'])){
$sql .= ' country='.$_GET['country'];  
} else {
$sql .= ' country=US';  
}

if(isset($_GET['state'])){
$sql .= ' and state='.$_GET['state'];  
}

if(isset($_GET['sub'])){
$sql .= ' and sub='.$_GET['sub'];  
}

//PDO
execute $SQL
```

This is how I do it. Is there a better, cleaner way to do this? Create sql statements on the fly based on the url? How would you do something like this?

Comment: apart from the security issues , seems fine to me, but this is not code review

Comment: Your code is susceptible to **[SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)**.

Comment: @dagon, @alias The `htaccess rules` allow only `a-z`. Do you think security is still a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Besides being vulnerable to SQL injections, there is nothing wrong with how you are going about doing this.

To prevent SQL injections, use prepared statements:

```
 $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
 $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
 $stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);
```

Specifically, the 'bindParam' method is what prevents the SQL injection by properly escaping the value in the query.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: The `htaccess rules` I have only allow `a-z`, and yes, I use `PDO`

Comment: @Norman see my updated example. Instead of appending to the $sql string, you should use the bindParam method $_GET['country'] and the other variables.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://j4mie.github.io/idiormandparis/

Idiorm is a fluent query builder, the above code would become:

```
$query = ORM::for_table('table_name')

if(isset($_GET['country'])){
    $query->where_equal('country', $_GET['country']);
} else {
    $query->where_equal('country', 'US');
}

if(isset($_GET['state'])) {
    $query->where_equal('state', $_GET['state']);
}

if(isset($_GET['sub'])) {
    $query->where_equal('sub', $_GET['sub']);
}

$results = $query->find_many();
```

Best of all this uses prepared statements so you get proper escaping closing a big security hole in your posted code above. (google for sql injection)

Answer (score 0):

Use [mysqli_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) if you are using MySQL.

Comment: Some more explanation/context on what you mean would be helpful for improving this answer.